# Remove any trailing alphanumeric characters from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have website in codeigniter. I am new to defining rule in .htaccess I want that if client types any alphanumeric character at end of URL those characters should be stripped off.

eg: In http://studio.com/gallery/babies/12abc

12abc should be removed.

Is there a way to do by setting a rule in .htaccess to remove any trailing alphanumeric characters?

I was searching rewrite rule for the same, but didnt find any. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just alphanumerics you want to remove...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(([^/]+/)*)([a-z0-9]+)$    $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

The two conditions `! -f` and `! -d` ensure the rewrite **only** happens if the URL doesn't point to a file (or directory) that actually exists - this prevents an URL that you actually want to go a specific, existent file/directory from being rewritten or you getting stuck in a horrible recursive loop causing Apache to throw a server error.

This .htaccess file needs to be at the root of your web server, if it's in a sub-directory you'll need to add the relevant `RewriteBase`.

The flags:

**NC** = No Case (makes the match case insensitive)

**R=301** = makes this redirect an actual HTTP 301 redirect so that your it'll change the URI (thus removing the unwanted trailing alphanumerics)

**L** = Last, we're done processing just redirect without checking the rest of the RewriteRules

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. But its not removing trailing characters from the URL

Comment: Ah yeah - sorry, it was mandating the trailing forward slash which may or may not be there ... updated

Comment: I get error 'The page isn't redirecting properly'. my webpage is not opening

Comment: @user44869 does the directory `/gallery/babies/` actually exist (e.g. it's a real file path rather than URL passed variables)? If it is **not** a file path you'll have a problem as you'll generate infinitely looping rewrites (which is what sounds like is happening).

Comment: gallery is model(MVC). In front end babies is sub menu which retrieves value from gallery model. so the url comes to http://studio.com/gallery/babies/ . Now if user types any character at end of URL, I want to remove it and keep URL as it is

Comment: @user44869 you're probably not going to be able to solve this (in a sensible manner) with a new `RewriteRule` **if** what you want to do is remove trailing characters from the URL (as displayed in the browser); the only way to remove those characters is to redirect to the URL without them. However your URLs are already being rewritten; they probably really go to somewhere like `/index.php?path=gallery/babies/12abc` so you need to find *that* RewriteRule and tweak it to remove the trailing characters and impose a *R=303* redirect - though that might *still* cause a loop.